# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum and ALAssetsLibrary not saving an image, no error either

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to save an image to the camera roll. This actually used to work wonderfully, but I had to work on other stuff and now I'm returning to the project to update it for iOS 6 and *poof* this feature no longer works at all on iOS6.

I have tried two approaches, both are failing silently without NSError objects. First, UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

// Callback
-(void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    // error == nil
}
```

... and the ALAssetsLibrary approach:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[img CGImage]
                          orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[img imageOrientation]
                      completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
{
    // assetURL == nil
    // error == nil
}
```

Also, `[ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus] == ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` evaluates to true

On the Simulator, the app never shows up in the Settings > Privacy > Photos section, however on an actual iPad they do show that the app has permission to access photos.  (Also, just to add:  The first approach above was what I previously used - it worked on real devices & simulators alike, no problem).

I have also tried running this on the main thread to see if that changed anything - no difference. I was running it on the background previously and it used to work fine (on both simulator and device).

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: I had a problem like this when saving to a custom assetsgroup. Except it would work intermittently. I solved the problem by just performing the selector after a delay of 0.1 until it succeeded. It always seems to work on the second attempt. The only thing I can think of causing this problem is the OS blocking your write attempt due to some locking issue. The other thing I would ask is, are you running this off of a background thread? and if so, is that allowed? if it is background, try from the main thread.

Comment: Yeah I tried executing it on the main thread, same result

Comment: Check that the app has not been denied access to the Photos in the Privacy Settings. - Is the `ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock` called at all? Are `assetURL` and `error` both `nil` in the completion block?

Comment: Yes, both are nil.. I'll edit the question to include that info.  Also, on the Simulator, Photo permissions don't appear, however on my iPad the permissions are open for my app.

Comment: Also, since this was the first time I was doing this on a real device with this app in iOS6, iOS triggered a prompt to allow this app to access photos when I hit the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum function, I tapped "Yes", now the app appeared in the Settings > Privacy > Photos section, but no photo.  That's when I switched to trying ALAssetsLibrary, but same result. Tried main thread, same result - silent failure with no photo saved, no error message, no uri.

Comment: This might be a crazy question, but is img a valid UIImage for saving? IOS6 may have introduced some extra restraint saying that certain dpi's are not allowed, or something crazy like that.

Comment: Do you know if there's any documentation that defines what's allowed and what's not?  I tried this in the non-retina iphone simulator, and the iPad 2, and no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... I was doing something stupid. UIImage cannot take raw pixel data, you have to first massage it into a form it can accept, with the proper metadata.

Part of the problem was that I was using Cocos2D to get a UIImage from a CCRenderTexture (getUIImageFromBuffer()) and when I switched to Cocos2D-x that function was no longer available, and I simply was ignorant to the fact that UIImage objects cannot be constructed with raw pixel data, I figured it handled header information & formatting automatically.

This answer helped: [iPhone - UIImage imageWithData returning nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135199/iphone-uiimage-imagewithdata-returning-nil)

And this example was also helpful:
http://www.wmdeveloper.com/2010/09/create-bitmap-graphics-context-on.html?m=1